# _setCampNameKey usage in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking at the js for google analytics on a page. It contains the following (changed the domain name, name etc). This is on the home page. I understand that these are used to set campaign variables but... why would someone do this on the home page? Perhaps because they have multiple sites and are tracking hits to each one as a campaign? Is this a good configuration?

```
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'somesite.co.uk']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampNameKey', 'John Doe']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampSourceKey', 'any']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampMediumKey', 'any']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampTermKey', 'plumbs']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampContentKey', 'all']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking a step further.  All the `_setCamp*Key` functions tell GA there to look in the `Key` -- not the value.  Take a closer look at the examples in the [GA Campaign Tracking Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCampContentKey)

Comment: Ah, thanks! So from the docs if the incoming link has a param description = 'xxx' then setCampContentKey is saying map whatever is in the description field to the standard utm_content field... but does that make sense for the example above? Wouldn't the line  _gaq.push(['_setCampContentKey', 'all']); indicate there is a param all='something' which should be mapped to utm_content?